# How can I run a add-on from a python script

Tags: add-on

I know how to enable the add-on through the script but I was wondering how to run the add-on. Meaning how do i use it through a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine there is an addon installed called "my addon". It has a couple properties to control in the toolshelf, and an operator.

The properties are all in bpy.context.scene.

In your script/addon, you can access all these properties.

You can set properties by

```
bpy.context.scene.my_addon_string = "hey"
```

And call operators

```
bpy.ops.object.my_addon_op()
```

So with a combination of editing properties and running operators, you should be able to run the addon from another addon or script.

Comment: how can i see what the already properties are, and how do i call them from the _op()

Comment: @AlexanderPagan if you hover over elements in the addon UI you can find source code paths and property names. Also you can read the source code of the addon.