# How do I run an existing add-on via the python API?

Tags: python, add-on

Very beginner question, but after extensive searching through the [addon tutorials](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/scripting/addon_tutorial.html) and [similar](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58213/how-can-i-run-a-add-on-from-a-python-script) [questions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-installed-addons-using-the-api) I do not see a clear way to run an existing enabled add on via the Python API.

In this case I am trying to run the Cell Fracture plugin on a new plane:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=50)
bpy.ops.object.particle_system_add()
# run cell fracture plugin
```

I do have the add on:

```
import addon_utils
for mod in addon_utils.modules():
    if mod.bl_info['name'] == 'Cell Fracture': 
        print(mod.bl_info)

# {'name': 'Cell Fracture', 'author': 'ideasman42, phymec, Sergey Sharybin', 'version': (0, 2), 'blender': (2, 80, 0), 'location': 'Viewport Object Menu -> Quick Effects', 'description': 'Fractured Object, Bomb, Projectile, Recorder', 'warning': '', 'wiki_url': 'http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/CellFracture', 'category': 'Object'}
```

But I don't see anything named `cell` anything in `bpy.ops.object` or `bpy.context.preferences.addons` or even `sys.modules`.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Addons register panels and operators**

An addon when enabled registers panels and operators and properties etc it uses. An operator, or set of, is generally the means an addon uses to "run".

The addon tells us where to look for the operator in the UI, in this case *`object menu > quick effects > Cell Fracture`*.  With [developer extras](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/preferences/interface.html#prefs-interface-dev-extras) turned on will see the operator is `bpy.ops.object.add_fracture_cell()`

[image]

To the python console.  What's important here is the module name, using code from question

```
>>> for mod in addon_utils.modules():
...     if mod.bl_info['name'] == 'Cell Fracture': 
...         mod
...         
<module 'object_fracture_cell' from '/home/batfinger/blender-git/v2.8/bin/2.83/scripts/addons/object_fracture_cell/__init__.py'>
```

To enable the addon

```
>>> addon_utils.enable("object_fracture_cell")
<module 'object_fracture_cell' from '/home/batfinger/blender-git/v2.8/bin/2.83/scripts/addons/object_fracture_cell/__init__.py'>
```

*Note* this pretty much calls the modules `register()` method. and could also be done via

```
object_fracture_cell.register()
```

Inspect the module. *Could eyeball this, via code or UI as described above.*

Similarly to https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/163366/15543 instead of panels will look for operators

```
>>> for p in dir(object_fracture_cell):
...     x = getattr(object_fracture_cell, p)
...     if inspect.isclass(x) and issubclass(x, bpy.types.Operator):
...         x, getattr(x, "bl_idname", "None")
...         
(<class 'object_fracture_cell.FractureCell'>, 'object.add_fracture_cell_objects')
(<class 'bpy_types.Operator'>, "None")

>>>
```

Telling us that cell fracture has one operator

```
bpy.ops.object.add_fracture_cell_objects()
```

Autocomplete gives us the arguments available to the operator

```
>>> bpy.ops.object.add_fracture_cell_objects(
add_fracture_cell_objects()
    >>> bpy.ops.object.add_fracture_cell_objects(
add_fracture_cell_objects()
bpy.ops.object.add_fracture_cell_objects(
        source={'PARTICLE_OWN'},
        source_limit=100, 
        source_noise=0, 
        cell_scale=(1, 1, 1), 
        recursion=0, 
        recursion_source_limit=8, 
        recursion_clamp=250, 
        recursion_chance=0.25, 
        recursion_chance_select='SIZE_MIN', 
        use_smooth_faces=False, 
        use_sharp_edges=True, 
        use_sharp_edges_apply=True, 
        use_data_match=True, 
        use_island_split=True, 
        margin=0.001, 
        material_index=0, 
        use_interior_vgroup=False, 
        mass_mode='VOLUME', 
        mass=1, 
        use_recenter=True, 
        use_remove_original=True, 
        collection_name="", 
        use_debug_points=False, 
        use_debug_redraw=True, 
        use_debug_bool=False)
(undocumented operator)
```

*In lieu of usng documentation link, while migratory*

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response, that works perfectly and gave me a great amount of relative knowledge as well I am sure that will come in handy!

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know why running one script would cause Blender to forget a default operator? I have a problem RN where my `_init_` file will break the `type` operator for the node tree.